# Python and Task Scheduler Monitoring

Tags: python, windows, scheduled-tasks, monitoring, scheduler

Currently, my team is using a Grafana Dashboard to gather information from the Task Scheduler periodically. It works "well," but we're unsure if it's the most optimized method.
When a script fails, the Task Scheduler generates error messages. However, how can we effectively manage this? I'm experimenting with the `exit()` function and its codes, but I'm still a bit confused...

Is there a more efficient way to monitor Python code using the Windows Task Scheduler?
We are using a Windows 2008 server, and all Python scripts are being executed in this manner.

Is there a better solution for monitoring my code on a server, and are there established patterns for its implementation?

Moreover, I appreciate in advance for any response or suggestion.

[Monitoring Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vrNR.png)

[PostgreSQL Tables with Scheduler Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlCz0.png)

Comment: If you are not satisfied with the task scheduler, check out [Taskopy](https://github.com/vikilpet/Taskopy). It has a built-in HTTP server, so you can get any information from your computer.